# Set titleLabel according to UIButton height

Tags: swift, layout, uibutton, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am in a situation, where i want to set the titleLabel's font-size of a UIButton element according to the height of the UIButton, so here is my setup:

```
let button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("title", for: [])
    button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(self.button)

    self.button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.someElement.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33).isActive = true
    self.button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true
    self.button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

What happens?

The buttons width is set to 33% of the view's width -> good

The buttons height is set to 10% of the view's height -> good

The buttons titleLabel font size stays small and doesnt scale with the buttons height... -> bad

Could anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to scale your label with the buttons height is adapting the font size in the `viewDidAppear` method. It is important that you do that in there and not in `viewDidLoad` since the buttons height is not yet known in `viewDidLoad`.

The following code snipped should scale the font size of your button to be half the size of the buttons height:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // If you use a custom font, you have to replace systemFont with it
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: button.frame.height * 0.5)
}
```

If your title becomes very long, it will, however, be scaled down to fit into the buttons width (because you have set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true).